# Move a key/value to the front

Tags: javascript

I don't know what to try here.

I have a list of users in a chat and I want the current user to be always at the top so I can use different functions on it, like editing his own profile instead of opening a private chat with itself.

Object looks like this:

```
connections: { [key: string]: Array<string> } = {};
```

Previously I was just deleting the key and use it separately but that created some bugs and I think is better if I just edit the key directly.
The way I did was like this:

```
delete this.connections[this.username];
```

And I wonder if I can use `this.connections[this.username]` to just place it at index 0 of the key/value pair type?

I honestly don't know what to try, for an array is easier to accomplish this but I haven't manipulated much key/value pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method.

It returns a copy of the object and then you should assign it again.

```js
let obj = {'b': 2, 'c': 3};
obj = Object.assign({'a': 1}, obj);
console.log(obj);
/* {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3} */
```

And also you can use the spread operator like this:

```js
let obj = {'b': 2, 'c': 3};
obj = {'a':1 , ...obj};
console.log(obj);
/* {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3} */
```

**But the best way to handle orders is to use Array instead of Object**